# IE8: Strange jQuery show element issue regardless the method (slide, show, fade)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drupal, internet-explorer-8, drupal-7

Here's another strange one curiosity of Microsoft. In IE8, when I attempt to show a particular element, regardless of the method (slide, show, fade), it doesn't show... but is there. So if you go to http://www.stratfor.com in IE8 and hover over a dropdown main menu link, you'll notice a small border that appears directly below the element which is part of the dropdown, but doesn't show the whole thing. Now move your mouse down and you'll notice the links are there and clickable, you just can't see them. When you click on a link, before the page reloads, the dropdown will appear.

It's gotta be something with how these elements are setup because on other areas of the site, there isn't this issue. I've tried different jQuery methods from hover to bind. I've set the dropdown as a block when page loads and shows correctly. I've set the dropdown as a block, hid it with jQuery once the page loads, and the behavior persists.

Here's the code below I'm using:

```
(function ($) {
  // Initialize the main menu dropdowns.
  Drupal.behaviors.mainMenu = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#block-system-main-menu .site-menu li', context).hover(
        function() {
          $(this).addClass('is-active');
          if ( $('.site-submenu', this).length ) {
            $('.site-submenu', this).slideDown('fast');
          }
        }, function() {
          $(this).removeClass('is-active');
          if ( $('.site-submenu', this ).length && $('.site-submenu', this).is(':visible')) {
            $('.site-submenu', this).hide();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Check out the CSS too, maybe I've got something in there that's off.

This one is driving me nuts. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I tried positioning the dropdown to the top instead of below the menu and that appears to help. It's seems a parent element of the dropdown is hiding (sorta, since you can still click on the links) the dropdown box once it goes past it's container.

**UPDATE:** When the dropdown menu is set to show by default, is shows as expected. Then hiding it, and showing it based off hover causes the issue again. I've also checked and re-checked positioning and z-index for parent elements. This a a strange one, because it works in IE7 and all other browserws and versions I've found except IE8.

Comment: For me it works fine in IE8 - Is your issue sometimes?

Comment: Would be mind shooting me a screenshot of it? I'm in a Mac shop so testing IE through a VM. I'm leaning towards something up with the VM and the screen refresh rate.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the Peekaboo Bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the screenshot in IE 8: (Works fine)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: excellent, thanks! let me confirm it with one more user and ill up your answer